# Which of the following are valid and what is the dimension of a and b?

Tags: java, arrays

Which of the following are valid and what is the size of a and b? I am using java language?

```
1. int[ ]   a, b;
2. int[ ]   a[ ], b;
3. int[ ]   a[ ], b[ ];
4. int[ ]   [ ]a, b;
5. int[ ]   [ ]a, b[ ];
6. int[ ]   [ ]a, [ ]b;
```

what is the dimension of a and b. how can i find its dimensions. and what is wrong with the last declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have typo instead of Int it should be int.

Answer :- if we want specify dimension before the variable, that facility is applicable only for first variable in a declaration. If we are trying to apply for remaining variables, we will get compile time error.

```
1. a=1, b=1;
2. a=2, b=1;
3. a=2, b=2;
4. a=2, b=2;
5. a=2, b=3;
6. Compile time error.
```

Comment: Not sure if your answer is even more confusing than the question...

Comment: @GyroGearless what is confusing here

Comment: e.g `b=3` last line, what would this mean?

Comment: it means b is three dimension array

Comment: `int [] [] a, [] b` is just syntactically wrong, so there is no array "b" of dimension 3?

Comment: bro actually there is littile bit confusion here, last one is comile time error, b=3 is the answer of 2nd last. let me give it numbering

Comment: OK, makes sense now